# Find the plane where the curve is situated.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given the curve:

$$c:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3 \quad c(t)=(3t-1, t^2-2, t^2+2t-1)$$

Let $x = 3t-1 , y = t^2-2, z = t^2+2t-1$

How can I find the plane equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to express one coordinate as linear combination of the others up to a constant, in this case by inspection we have that

$$z=y+\frac23x+\frac53 \iff 2x+3y-3z=-5$$

As an alternative we need to find $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that

$$ax+by+cz=d$$

then plug in the values in $t$ to obtain

$$3at-a+bt^2-2b+ct^2+2ct-c=d$$

$$(b+c)t^2+(3a+2c)t-a-2b-c=d$$

that is

- $a=k$
- $b=-c=\frac32 k$
- $d=-\frac52k$

Comment: I'm a beginner in this kind of problems, so any explicit demonstration will be welcomed

Comment: I get a = k, b = -3k/2 , c = 3k/2 and d = -k/2

Comment: @Akhtubir Plugging $x=\frac23$ this solution doesn't correspond to mine. I add that in the answer to check.

Comment: @Akhtubir:Idea is to eliminate $t$. Find $t$ from the equation in $x$ to get: 
$t=\frac{x+1}{3}$. Now get $t^2$ from the second equation to get $t^2=y+2$. 
Put these into the third eqn. to get relation amongst $x,y$ and $z$.

Comment: @Akhtubir I've added the general solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

If $c(t) \in \Pi$ then

$$
(c(t)-c(0))\cdot \vec n = d,\ \ \ \vec n = (u,v,w)
$$

or

$$
(3t-1+1)u+(t^2-2+2)v+(t^2+2t-1+1)w=d,\ \ \forall t
$$

so grouping

$$
(3u+2w)t + (v+w)t^2 = d,\ \ \forall t
$$

and this is possible only if

$$
\cases{
3u+2w=0\\
v+w=0\\
d=0\\
u^2+v^2+w^2=1
}
$$

The condition $u^2+v^2+w^2=1$ has normalizing purposes and was included to avoid the trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

The curve lies in a plane if there's a (normal) vector $\vec n$ such that
$$\langle c(t)-c((0),\vec n\rangle=0\qquad(\ast).$$
One may choose for the normal vector the cross product of $\dot c(0)=(3,0,2)$ and $\ddot c(0)=(0,2,2)$ which is $\vec n=(-4,-6,6)$.  Now verify that $(\ast)$ holds for that $\vec n$.